# changing the color of sub text box

Tags: javascript, text, colors, box

I'm writing a code for medication tracking using javascript,the thing is: I've created a `textbox` ,inside that `textbox` I've further created another `textbox` (sub textbox), now I need to change the color of that sub textbox. If the condition is true, then it should go green, and if the condition is false, then it should go red.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

jQuery:

```
$('#textbox').on('keyup', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var chk = "medicine"
    var val = $(this).val();

    if(val == chk)
    {
        $(this).find(":input").css("background-color", "green");
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).find(":input").css("background-color", "red");
    }
}
```

or if You know name/id of Yours input:

```
$('#textbox').on('keyup', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var chk = "medicine"
    var val = $(this).val();

    if(val == chk)
    {
        $(this).find("#subtextbox").css("background-color", "green");
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).find("#subtextbox").css("background-color", "red");
    }
}
```

or pure js:

```
$('#textbox').on('keyup', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var chk = "medicine"
    var val = $(this).val();

    if(val == chk)
    {
        document.getElementById('subtextbox').style.background-color = "green";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('subtextbox').style.background-color = "red";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could help

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<p>type the word medicine</p>
<input type="text" id="textbox" value="">
<input type="text" id="subtextbox" value="">

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#textbox').on('keyup', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        // make the condition here
        // make this dynamic
        var chk = "medicine"
        var val = $(this).val();

        var sub = $('#subtextbox');
        if (chk == val) {
            sub.css('background-color', 'green');
        } else {
            sub.css('background-color', '');
        }

    });

});



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is what i really ment ,

Comment: document.getElementById("bodyRow3Col_1").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
        document.getElementById("bodyRow3Col_1InrCol_0").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        document.getElementById("bodyRow3Col_1InrCol_1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        document.getElementById("bodyRow3Col_1InrCol_2").style.backgroundColor = "blue";

Comment: this is what i really ment ,where i have created a subtext-box inside a main text box,i need that subtext-box color to be changed red and green on true or false condition .

Comment: I can't really understand what you really mean

maybe posting the html code. we can understand it more better

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
document.getElementById('your subtext id').style.background-color = "green";
```